# Direct proof (or reference) that a given $p$-group is extra-special

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, presentations-of-groups

Writing a paper on algebraic surfaces, I was led to consider the finite group $\mathsf{H}(A)$ whose presentation is the following.

I start  with an anti-symmetric matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ of order $2n$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (the finite group/field with $p$ elements), $p \geq 3$, and I consider the following system of generators and relations:

**Generators:**

$x_1, \ldots, x_{2n}, \; z$

**Relations:**
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x_1^p &= \ldots=x_{2n}^p=z^p=1 \\
[x_1, \, z] &= \ldots = [x_{2n}, \, z]=1\\
[x_i, \, x_j]& =z^{a_{ij}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where, by slight abuse of notation, the exponent $a_{ij}$ stands for any lifting in $\mathbb{Z}$ of $a_{ij} \in \mathbb{Z_p}$.

I can prove the following

> **Proposition 1.** If $\det A \neq 0$, then the group $\mathsf{H}(A)$ presented as above is extra-special of order $p^{2n+1}$ and exponent $p$.

*Proof*. Calling $\omega$ the symplectic form on the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-vector space $V:=(\mathbb{Z}_p)^{2n}$ whose matrix (with respect to the standard basis) is $A$, one checks that $\mathsf{H}(A)$ is isomorphic to the [Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) $\mathsf{H}(V, \, \omega)$. By standard linear algebra, up to a change of coordinates the symplectic form $\omega$ can be transformed into the standard symplectic form $\omega_{\mathrm{st}}$, so our group is also isomorphic to $\mathsf{H}(V, \, \omega_{\mathrm{st}})$, that has the desired properties, being the central product of $n$ copies of the $p$-group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$. $\square$

Now, I was asked by the referee to give a *direct* proof of Proposition 1, namely a proof not involving symplectic forms. The motivation for this request is that the present proof is a bit far from the spirit of the paper, whose emphasis is mainly on group presentations.

Of course, I can give an equivalent proof involving nonsingular anti-symmetric matrices instead of symplectic forms, but I suspect that this is not what he/she/other pronoun was asking for. So let me ask the following two questions.

> **Question 1.** Is there a proof of Proposition 1 essentially different from the one I gave?
>
> **Question 2.** Is there any precise reference for Proposition 1?

I suspect that all of this is very well-known to the experts. Any hint to orientate myself in the extensive literature on $p$-groups would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is clear from standard properties on commutators that $H(A)$ is nilpotent of class at most $2$ with derived group and Frattini subgroup contained in $\langle z \rangle$
(just consider $H(A)/\langle z \rangle$, which is elementary Abelian of order $p^{2n})$.

The general property of commutators that you need is that we always have $[a,bc] = [a,b]^{c}[a,c]$. It is this, combined with the last relation(s), that ensures that the derived group of $H(A)$ is containedd in $\langle z \rangle$. It is necessary $A$ is antisymmetric, since we have $[x_{j},x_{i}] = [x_{i},x_{j}]^{-1}.$

The only remaining issue is check that $H(A)$ has center $\langle z \rangle$ (but no larger). This requires that $x_{1}^{b_{1}} x_{2}^{b_{2}} \ldots x_{2n}^{b_{2n}}$ is not central when $0 \leq b_{i} \leq p-1$ and not all $b_{i}$ are zero.

Using the above commutator relation $[a,bc] = [a,b]^{c}[b,c]$ repeatedly, and taking the commutator of the above element with each $x_{k}$, we see that this is equivalent to the non-singularity of $A$.

Comment: Ah, of course, fixed. Thank you very much for the answer, I will check the details.

Comment: In fact, since the group defined by the presentation clearly has nilpotency class at most 2 (it would be abelian if all of the $a_{ij}$ were 0),  the commutator relation simplifies to $[a,bc] = [a,b][a,c]$, which make checking easier.

Comment: It suffices to check the commutator relation for $a, \, b, \, c, \,$ of the form $$x_1^{t_1}x_2^{t_2}\ldots x_{2n}^{t_{2n}},$$
right?

Comment: @DerekHolt : Yes, I was implicitly using the fact that $[x_{i},x_{j}]$ is central in this case (from the given relations), but perhaps I should have made this explicit.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi : You only need to check $[x_{k},x_{1}^{b_{1}} \ldots x_{2n}^{b_{2n}}]$ for each $k$, and this turns out to be $z^{b_{1}a_{k1} + \ldots + b_{2n}a_{k 2n}}$ in each case.

Comment: Isn't the condition required equivalent to the antisymmetric bilinear form defined by $A$ being non-degenerate, which is euqivalent to $A$ being non-singular?

Comment: @DerekHolt : I am not sure whether this was addressed to Francesco or me (or both). The question was to give a "direct" proof without using symplectic forms. But of course, extraspeciaal groups and symplecctic forms are inseparable, and it is certainly the case that the symplectic form proof and the above "direct" group-theoretic proof are equivalent, just using a different language.

Comment: Geoff and Derek: yes, for the reasons your are giving I suspect that every proof will be equivalent to the original one. However, I would like to comply with the referee's request, possibly learning some math during the process. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Geoff Robinson and @DerekHolt: I have checked the details and everything works, thank you again for the clear and elegant proof. It seems to me that, exactly with the same argument, one can show that, if $A=(a_{ij})$ is 
non-singular, then the group
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x_1^p &= \ldots=x_{2n-2}^p=z^p=1 \\
x_{2n-1}^p & =x_{2n}^p=z \\
[x_1, \, z] &= \ldots = [x_{2n}, \, z]=1\\
[x_i, \, x_j]& =z^{a_{ij}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
is extra-special of order $p^{2n+1}$ and exponent $p^2$, right?

Comment: In fact, if I am not mistaken, just one relation of type $x_j^p=z$ is sufficient to force the exponent to be $p^2$...

Comment: For the first question, I think everything does go through with hardly any modification. Calling $G(A)$, the new group, it is clear that $G(A)/\langle z \rangle$ is elementary Abelian of order $p^{2n}$, so $G(A)$ has class at most $2$ and all its commutators are central (and, from general properties of class $2$ groups, the exponent is $p^{2}$). The linear independence of the rows of $A$ is equivalent to the fact that $\langle z \rangle$ is precisely the center of $G(A)$, just as before. As for the last question, yes, one such relation forces the group to have exponent $p^{2}$.

Comment: Thanks again! So the dichotomy is 

**(1)** all the relations in the first row are of type $x_j^p=1$: the exponent is $p$; 

**(2)** there is at least one relation of type $x_j^p=z$: the exponent is $p^2$.

By the classification of extra-special $p$-groups, we know that two such groups with the same order and exponent are  isomorphic (at least if $p$ is odd), so the isomorphism class in the second case does not depend on the number of relations of type $x_j^p=z$.

Comment: And the isomorphism class of the group does not depend on $m$, as soon as $m >0$, right?

Comment: I think that's right, since there are only two isomorphism types of extraspecial group of order $p^{2n+1}$, so I was overcomplicating things.